# Where did compression go when exporting glb models?

Tags: export, gltf, compression

I currently have Blender 3.4.0 installed, which lacks the ability to compress the GLB model.
Earlier versions had this feature. How can I turn it on now or where can I find it?

[image: Blender v<3.4]

[image: Blender 3.4.0]

Comment: Look on th 'N'  panel in the file selector when you select export. It's in the Geometry section.

Comment: In the second screenshot, I showed this panel, which is missing Geometry and Compression...

Comment: Apologies. It was almost 1am when I posted that and it turned out I had 3.3 open not 3.4! The Geometry entry including Compression is still in the Blender 3.4 [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/scene_gltf2.html#geometry) so I suggest you report it as a bug which you can do in the Preferences > addons entry (and mention that it's in the manual if they say it's been removed!).

Comment: Thanks to. I'll try

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the entries in the Geometry section are all now in the dropdown labeled 'Data' including the Compression checkbox in Blender 3.4:

[image]

Comment: Regarding my previous comment, the "bug" is that the Blender manual hasn't been updated  for 3.4!

Comment: Apparently I don't have Compression. It may be related to the Linux operating system

Comment: That does surprise me! Can anyone here using Linux confirm that? (I use Windows 10.)

Comment: This problem sometimes occurs due to python in Linux distributions.
https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO/issues/1826